# how to add default value like "Select" in Ember.Select

Tags: ember.js

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="ResAdmin.adminController.priceCategories"
                    valueBinding="selectedRestaurant.PriceCategoryID"
                    optionLabelPath="content.name"
                    optionValuePath="content.id"}}
```

how can i add the default value like "Please select Restaurant" as first value of ember select list? Any direct way available??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{view Ember.Select prompt="Please select Restaurant"}}`

I recommend that you read the unit tests for the parts of Ember that you have questions about. They can reveal a lot of undocumented functionality and give examples on how to use them.

Comment: from where i can read the unit tests for the parts of Ember?? i am not able to find the good documentation on ember

Comment: Simply go to http://github.com/emberjs/ember.js and hit `t` which lets you browse through the files. If you enter `test` you'll get a list of all files with test in its name. The test for `Ember.Select` is in https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/tests/controls/select_test.js